# How could someone use teleportation for international travel without anyone knowing

Tags: teleportation

The setting is our world.
The character obtains a teleportation device.

How can it use it for international travel without being caught or discovering the teleportation ability?

Some ideas:
If you just teleport to another country you won't enter it legally

Would you teleport to the restrooms in an airport just before border control? Will they know you didn't fly in?

Comment: VTC: This seems like a question that is highly dependent upon the rules your world has for teleportation, and the specific actions of characters and organizations within your world take to monitor teleportation. In it's current form this question is unanswerable without us brainstorming how teleportation works in your world. Since this is also dependent upon specific actions of characters and organizations, without those being specified this question will also be unanswerable.

Comment: The details of teleportation are not critical, you can basically appear where ever you want. The idea is to design a "system" that will allow the character to use teleportation for travel without being detected

Comment: Without knowing how teleportation works, you can't know what measures can be used to detect teleportation. Without knowing what measures are in use to detect teleportation you cannot know how to avoid detection.

Comment: VTC: (a) You are allowed to ask one and only one question. (b) Your question is too story-based. (c) You set the rules of teleportation in your world, you have not defined or explained any of those rules. (d) Per the [help/on-topic], we are here to help you build your world, not tell your story. Whether or not someone can do anything without detection is storybuilding. How the rules of teleportation work on your world is worldbuilding. (e) You need to research international travel.

Comment: *"If you just teleport to another country you won't enter it legally"* . . . unless your home country and your destination country have a free-travel arrangement, such as for example, the member states of the European Union, or the United Kingdom and Ireland. One can travel from Romania to Finland in any way one likes, and as long as they carry their Romanian ID they are totally within their rights to be in Finland, and nobody can ask in what way they arrived.

Comment: I would not use an airport, I would use a land border,

Comment: Gee, Senator, it would be great if teleporting into bank vaults, museums, and the National Gold Depository wasn't such a crime anymore. I'd like to make a donation to your re-election fund. Do you take gold ingots?

Answer (score 7):

## Just Do It

You just teleport there. Go to the general area you want to get to, but select a place where people will not see you come in. Bathrooms, for instance, or parks in the wee hours of the morning are generally private places where no one would see you.

In my limited international travel experience, normal people do not challenge you for your passport. Even when everything about you *screams* "FOREIGNER," people don't even know what to do if you did enter illegally or do not possess a passport.

Boarder patrol or government officials do ask for this, but they are rarely the ones guarding the interesting stuff. They are not at the tourist attractions, your foreign friend's house, or at the market. Unless it is a tightly controlled country, no one is going to ask questions.

## Legal/Honest Methods

It depends on the country you are getting into, but you could easily claim a misplaced ticket when going through customs. Especially if you are at the end of a boarder guard's shift, they may accept a valid passport without any knowledge of how you got there. Doubly so if in a place where there is a good assumption on how you got there without much control, like a foot bridge or road!

Comment: Claiming a misplaced ticket won't work in many places, particularly airports. This is because airlines are required to report passenger manifests to immigration. You will want a crossing that deals with anonymous transportation.

Comment: @gene good point, I have incorporated it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest the person plan ahead. Have an apartment in the other country, that has your passport in it, under a different name. Buy a refundable ticket from the target country to somewhere else, cheap. A short hop. Teleport to that apartment. Travel normally to the airport, as if leaving. Use the ticket and your ID to get into the boarding area. Have your suitcase with you.

Use for phone to cancel the ticket and get your refund. Then use your normal ID, and normal passport, to exit through customs, and get your passport stamped. Leaving: do the same thing in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

> Would you teleport to the restrooms in an airport just before border control? Will they know you didn't fly in?

They would. In the post-9/11 world, airline passengers are listed ahead of time, and a person showing up at the airport without being on any flight will raise all sorts of alarm.

But if you contemplate going through passport control, then the character would need a valid visa or whatever (double nationality, right of visa-free entry ...). If the character commutes between just a few countries, there are legal ways to get multiple identity documents, and judicious juggling would make sure the right papers show the right status.

For example: The character is a citizen of some EU country which issues ID cards and (at need) multiple passports who also has a Green Card for the US. Fly from Europe to the US to get the entry recorded. Teleport home. Use the ID card for travel within the EU and those countries around it which accept it. Use the other passport to travel from the EU to the UK. Teleport from the UK to the US. ...

Answer (score 2):

**Your character is a master of disguise!**

[image: sellers the salty swedish sea dog]

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/141793088239827684/

Apparate where no-one is looking.  Ho.  In dark parks.  Hum.  In apartments he owns where he has some spare shorts.  Ho hum.  Where is the pizzazz, I ask you?

Nay.  Your character is a master of disguise and he works hard at it.  When he (or she?  The disguises are good!) apparates in a furrin land, no-one knows who it is!  "A mysterious stranger!" they say.  "A dancing vagrant! Ronald Reagan, but a redhead! A sexy lady in a camouflage tuxedo!"  All of those things, but the same individual.  Your character never chooses the same disguise twice.

No-one knows he is using a teleportation device to travel because no-one knows it is him (her?).